How to create an Azure VM (using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute) with an existing snapshot copied over to the OSDisk
With the previous SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent) I was able to do something like this:
ISnapshot snapshot = azure.Snapshots.GetById(snapshotId);
Console.WriteLine("Creating os disk for vm...");
IDisk disk = azure.Disks.Define(vmOSDiskName)
    .WithRegion(vmRegion)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(vmResourceGroupName)
    .WithWindowsFromSnapshot(snapshot)
    .WithSizeInGB(128)
    .WithSku(DiskSkuTypes.SStandardSSDLRS)
    .Create(); 

if (disk != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating virtual machine from Snapshot...");
    IVirtualMachine vm = await azure.VirtualMachines.Define(vmName)
        .WithRegion(vmRegion)
        .WithExistingResourceGroup(vmResourceGroupName)
        .WithExistingPrimaryNetworkInterface(networkInterface)
        .WithSpecializedOSDisk(disk, OperatingSystemTypes.Windows)
        .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardE2sV3)
        .CreateAsync();

    return vm;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to create os disk for vm...");
}

And even with PowerShell I can utilize the same snapshot in this manner:
$snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName
Write-Host "Creating Disk Config"
$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -AccountType StandardSSD_LRS -Location $snapshot.Location -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -CreateOption Copy
Write-Host "Creating OS Disk"
$disk = New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $osDiskName
#Initialize virtual machine configuration
Write-Host "Creating VM Config"
$VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $virtualMachineName -VMSize $virtualMachineSize
Write-Host "Updating VM config with OS Disk"
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows
Write-Host "Creating virtual machine and powering on"
New-AzVM -VM $VirtualMachine -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $snapshot.Location

I am not finding examples with Azure.ResourceManager.Compute that would allow me to leverage existing snapshots.
Does Azure.ResourceManager.Compute have the capability to do that and are there code samples of that?
I am trying to migrate from Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent, which is deprecated, to Azure.ResourceManager.Compute, but the samples and documentation are lacking.


How to create an Azure VM (using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute) with an existing snapshot copied over to the OSDisk.

To create an Azure Virtual Machine (VM) with an existing snapshot copied over to the OSDisk (using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute), use the following .NET code.
Code:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

        string subscriptionId = "xxxx";
        string resourceGroupName = "xxxx";
        ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName);
        ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);

        // Get the resource group to populate its data
        resourceGroupResource = await resourceGroupResource.GetAsync();

        ManagedDiskCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetManagedDisks();

        string diskName = "impdisk123";
        ManagedDiskData data = new ManagedDiskData(new AzureLocation("East US"))
        {
            CreationData = new DiskCreationData(DiskCreateOption.Copy)
            {
                SourceResourceId = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxe/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/venkatsnap1"),
            },
        };
        ArmOperation<ManagedDiskResource> lro = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, diskName, data);
        ManagedDiskResource result = lro.Value;
        ManagedDiskData resourceData = result.Data;

        VirtualMachineCollection vmCollection = resourceGroupResource.GetVirtualMachines();
        string vmName = "vm345";
        VirtualMachineData input = new VirtualMachineData(resourceGroupResource.Data.Location)
        {
            HardwareProfile = new VirtualMachineHardwareProfile()
            {
                VmSize = VirtualMachineSizeType.StandardB2S
            },
            NetworkProfile = new VirtualMachineNetworkProfile()
            {
                NetworkInterfaces =
                {
                    new VirtualMachineNetworkInterfaceReference()
                    {
                        Id = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/samplenic"),
                        Primary = true,
                    }
                }
            },
            StorageProfile = new VirtualMachineStorageProfile
            {
                OSDisk = new VirtualMachineOSDisk(DiskCreateOptionType.Attach)
                {
                    OSType = SupportedOperatingSystemType.Windows,
                    ManagedDisk = new VirtualMachineManagedDisk
                    {
                        Id = resourceData.Id,
                    }
                },
            },
        };

        try
        {
            ArmOperation<VirtualMachineResource> vlro = await vmCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, vmName, input);
            VirtualMachineResource vm = vlro.Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"Virtual machine created with ID: {vm.Data.Id}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to create the virtual machine: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

The above code first creates a disk from the snapshot and then creates a virtual machine using that disk.
Output:
Virtual machine created with ID: /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm345


Portal:

Reference:
Disks - Create Or Update - REST API (Azure Compute) | Microsoft Learn
